# Can't understand this Java GridLayout program

Tags: java

The below code is extraction from a Java program. The program code is very big so I am just posting the needed part. In the code, what does the `if (i == 2)` do? What does it check, and how can it check for 2?

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4, 5, 5));

String[] buttons = {
    "Cls", "Bck", "", "Close", "7", "8", "9", "/", "4", 
    "5", "6", "*", "1", "2", "3", "-", "0", ".", "=", "+"
};


for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

    if (i == 2) 
        panel.add(new JLabel(buttons[i]));
    else 
        panel.add(new JButton(buttons[i]));
}
```

Comment: OK , i understood guys , i didn't see i had a JLabel in that program , i thought both were Jbuttons

Comment: Tormod's answer is much more simple for me to undertsand....srry if others feel bad checking his answer as correct one ... Thanks to all , especially  polygenelubricants and paxdiablo (upvote from me)

Comment: No need to apologise for choosing the answer that best helped you out. That's how the whole system works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
```

The `for` statement creates the variable `i` at value `0`. Then it runs the code between `{` and `}` one time for each value in the array `buttons` (a list structure), increasing the variable `i` for each time.

The first time through, the line `if (i == 2)` will fail, because `i` is still `0`, and then calling the code after the `else`statement. This adds a button with the text `Cls`.

The third time through the code the variable `i` will be `2` (because it started at zero), and then it will run the line after `if (i == 2)` - because that is what it does.

It will then add a an empty label (the third entry in the array `buttons`, arrays start at `0` for the first position.) instead of a button.

I suggest having a look at [the Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) for more information on the language and structures of it. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's creating a 4-column by 5-row grid and putting buttons into all but the third one (offset 2). The third one is left blank by putting a label in there.

So what you're getting is the following calculator layout with no button in that third spot:

```
+-------+-------+       +-------+
|  Cls  |  Bck  |       | Close |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   7   |   8   |   9   |   /   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   4   |   5   |   6   |   *   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   -   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   0   |   .   |   =   |   +   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

It just an easy way to put a list of buttons together in a short loop, with a bit of a kludge to ensure the layout doesn't have a button that does nothing.

---

For what it's worth, I think the following would be better so that you don't rely on absolute positions:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4, 5, 5));
String[] buttons = {
    "Cls"  , "Bck"  , null   , "Close",
    "7"    , "8"    , "9"    , "/"    ,
    "4",   , "5"    , "6"    , "*"    ,
    "1"    , "2"    , "3"    , "-"    ,
    "0"    , "."    , "="    , "+"
};

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i] == null)
        panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    else 
        panel.add(new JButton(buttons[i]));
}
```

That just relies on one piece of information, the one in the `buttons` array. Of course, it assumes you only want blank labels but, in this case, it's okay since that's all they're being used for.

Comment: yes u right but still cant understand why cls comes first if i ==2 , "" should come 1st

Comment: @subanki, i goes from 0 to 19 no matter what. When it's 0, it adds the button `Cls`. When it's 1, it adds the button `Bck`. When it's two, it adds the _label_ `""`. Then it adds the remaining buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Given `int i`, `i == 2` evaluates to `true` if and only if `i` happens to contain the value 2. Otherwise it's `false`.

Thus:

```
if (i == 2) {
   // code executed if i has the value 2
} else {
   // code executed if i does NOT have the value 2
}
```

Note that arrays are zero-indexed. So given this declaration:

```
String[] buttons = {
    "Cls", "Bck", "", "Close", "7", "8", "9", "/", "4", 
    "5", "6", "*", "1", "2", "3", "-", "0", ".", "=", "+"
};
```

We have:

- `buttons[0].equals("Cls")`
- `buttons[1].equals("Bck")`
- `buttons[2].isEmpty()`

The entire `for` loop therefore goes through each element in `String[] buttons`, and for each element except at index 2 (these elements happen to be the ones that aren't empty string), it adds a `JButton` with that label to the panel. For the element at index 2 (which happens to be the empty string), it adds a `JLabel` instead.

Note that the `GridLayout` has 5 rows and 4 columns by the [constructor used](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), so essentially the code creates the following layout:

```
    _______________________________
   |       |       |       |       |
   |  Cls  |  Bck  |<blank>| Close |
   |_______|_______|_______|_______|
   |       |       |       |       |
   |   7   |   8   |   9   |   /   |
   |_______|_______|_______|_______|
   |       |       |       |       |
   |   4   |   5   |   6   |   *   |
   |_______|_______|_______|_______|
   |       |       |       |       |
   |   1   |   2   |   3   |   -   |
   |_______|_______|_______|_______|
   |       |       |       |       |
   |   0   |   .   |   =   |   +   |
   |_______|_______|_______|_______|
```

---

#### A `println` example

To understand the `for` loop logic itself, consider the following snippet:

```
    String[] buttons = {
        "Cls", "Bck", "", "Close",
        "7", "8", "9", "/",
        "4", "5", "6", "*",
        "1", "2", "3", "-",
        "0", ".", "=", "+"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println(buttons[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("[" + buttons[i] + "]");
        }
    }
```

The above prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/H5ijS)):

```
[Cls]
[Bck]

[Close]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[/]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[*]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[-]
[0]
[.]
[=]
[+]
```

Going back to the `GridLayout`, the order that the strings are printed in the above snippet is also the order the components are added into the `Panel`, in left-to-right, from-top-to-bottom order (i.e. [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major) order).

Comment: accroding to the output , cls comes first, followed by Bck , "", ........if u say that indezing is from 0 then how can cls come first , blank "" shoukld come first !!!

Answer (score 0):

The `String[] buttons` defines the text to display on a set of buttons to lay out on the panel (it looks like for a calculator program).  Note that the third entry (index 2) is an empty String `""`.  The code you listed inserts an empty label instead of a button in that position.

Answer (score 0):

Its creating **Calculator's** key pad.
Keeping third column in first row as JLable with empty text.

Wow someone has put how it will look. That should answer it all.